# Opposite Abbreviations

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge, english

What common word in the English language has two common abbreviations in opposite directions?

**Hint:**

> The word can be abbreviated **to** two opposite directions.

**A more explicit hint:**

> For example, swine->sw(i)ne might hypothetically be abbreviated to 'sw' and 'ne', being the abbreviations at the beginning and end of the word. However, even though sw and ne are actual opposite directions (south-west and north-east) , they are not at all usual stand-ins for swine...

**A further clarification:**

> Weekend or whatever might both be abbreviated as w/e, and w and e (west and east) would work. However, w/e is only one abbreviation. We want two.

This is taking a while to crack, so, here's **an even more explicit hint**:

> It's a **very** common five-letter word. The abbreviations are two letters each. One of the abbreviations is maybe even more common than the word itself, but the other is fairly common as well.

Comment: Opposite directions, like? Not exactly clear what you are asking for...

Comment: Sorry, I've voted to close as "unclear what you're asking" since I have no idea what "abbreviated in two opposite directions" means. Please ping me if you [edit] to clarify, and I'll retract my close vote :-)

Comment: As a guess, palindrome words come to my mind.

Comment: I would have thought the tags would have been enough to disambiguate. This has one single one-word clear answer which (as far as I know) is unique and self-evident once you know the answer. I really can't say much more without giving it away completely. Palindrome words are way off the mark.

Comment: This is a puzzle, why is it supposed to be more clear what one is asking? "What common word in the English language" should be pretty clear regarding the answer format.

Comment: Now based from the edit, OP is looking for an English word ABCDEF where ABCDEF can be abbreviated like CDEF and ABCD where both are valid abbreviations? Is this right? If so, I think the question is now clear?

Comment: OK you want a word like KO ?

Comment: @ABcDexter No, not at all, but at least it's a guess. :) Tag says wordplay. Go with that.

Comment: Whoever added the proposed edit I just rejected, you're probably on the right track. I added your bit as a hint instead.

Comment: If, by abbreviated, you just mean shortened, as in cutting off part of the word, it could be something like *swine->sw(i)ne* with 'sw' and 'ne' being the abbreviations at the beginning and end of the word (ie abbreviated *in* opposite directions) and actually being directions (abbreviated *to* opposite directions).  But there are tons of words that could fit this pattern...

Comment: @tmpearce You're on the right track. 'sw' and 'ne' are not abbreviations of the word swine, though. Find one where they are. :)

Comment: Sorry, this site only accepts puzzles that are clear. Or, I guess, questions.

Comment: Is the answer "whatever" because it abbreviates to w/e, which you can take as west and east?

Comment: @JoãoMendes I voted to reopen when the question was on its [third revision](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/45626/revisions) - didn't realise that edit was made by another user though ...

Comment: @user1566694 Good one. That's only one abbreviation, though. Find one with two. I'll add that to make it clearer.

Comment: @timme "Weekend" is not the answer either, for the same reason that "whatever" is not it. We need two abbreviations. Good effort, though. :)

Comment: So a word that can be abbreviated into, for example, nw and se?

Comment: For example, yes. If and when this question ever gets cleared, I'm hoping all these comments will be duly purged...

Comment: Meh, where's the fun in that. You have the only question that was tried at this hard in comments... Not sure if we're beating the 'wordplay' tag out of it tho

Comment: This is wrong too, but I like this puzzle now. Is it "Return", which you *can* abbreviate to rtn or rtrn (return) or ret (retreat)? OR is it The Christian Commonwealth (CCW), better known by Christians as simply The Commonwealth (CW), which isn't "common" in the common sense, but "common" in a different sense?

Comment: @user1566694 Now that the puzzle is no longer on hold, you might want to post attempts as answers instead? :) In any case, "return" doesn't fit the question and hints at all. The CCW guess is wrong too, although it makes a stellar use of the concept of wordplay! :) +1

Comment: I'm still missing something I guess (tho I thought I had it with Christian Commonwealth)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is (probably not, but you keep saying "common" so much I feel like I have to guess something)

> Hello

---

Which abbreviates more commonly than itself to the two-letter...

> Hi

And less commonly, tho some would argue never at all, to the two-letter, and one apostrophe...

> 'lo

Which are opposite directions if taken as...

> High and Low

Making the answer, as hinted

> A **very** common five-letter word, with one abbreviation so common no one really thinks of it as an abbreviation

Comment: And there you go. :) I thought that final hint might just give it away...

Comment: The "common abbreviation" isn't an abbreviation.  It's a different word.  No wonder nobody solved this.

Comment: really? wow... now what will i do with the rest of my week...

Comment: @Rubio, hence wordplay. British Dictionary definitions of "hi" include "an informal word for hello". I don't think it's that much of a stretch to call it an abbreviation. But, now that the answer is out there, suggestions on how to improve the original wording are most welcome.

Comment: @JoãoMendes Yes. It's a different word.  *Abbreviation* has a specific meaning, and suggesting an intentional misuse of it is "wordplay" is .. well...  you're now in [this territory](https://xkcd.com/169/).  I actually went through every 5 letter word in the 1000 most frequent English words lists—all 3 of them—twice. Your word is in all of them. I didn't give it a second glance, because there's *maybe* one abbreviation for it, but there certainly isn't two.  You can't have it both ways, by using one thing that actually *is* an abbreviation, and one that manifestly isn't.

Comment: @JoãoMendes Agreed with Rubio... They're synonymous words with separate etymologies, nothing more. That's like saying that "seat" is an abbreviation for "chair".

Answer (score 0):

An attempt or two. Could it be:

> Learns abbreviated as
>  
>  *Lrns* which has two opposite directions: Left - Right & North - South
>
>  An abbreviation for learn is given [here](http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/Learn) as LRN

If OK a backup with more wordplay is:

> Cartoons with abbreviation *toons*  : to (maybe wordplay) + o(opposite) + ns

Comment: No, sorry, none of these. You need two different common abbreviations for the word.